# How to retrieve a column from a dataframe that is embedded in a column of another dataframe?

Tags: r

My `idat.meta` dataframe has a column `associated_entities`, which comprises another dataframe (herein known as 2nd dataframe). I want to retrieve the first column of this second dataframe for all the rows in `idat.meta` using list comprehension.

My attempt returns a list of lists. I want strings, not lists.

```
for(rows in idat.meta$associated_entities){
  print(unlist(rows[[1]]))
}
```

Data:

```
> dput(idat.meta[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(data_format = c("IDAT", "IDAT", "IDAT", "IDAT", 
"IDAT"), access = c("open", "open", "open", "open", "open"), 
    associated_entities = list(structure(list(entity_submitter_id = "TCGA-B3-4103-11A-01D-1191-05", 
        entity_type = "aliquot", case_id = "1a726069-0b44-42ad-9a20-0ee90b31796b", 
        entity_id = "c0d3e15c-bc4e-432b-9cf0-3bf2b8411c57"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(entity_submitter_id = "TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05", 
            entity_type = "aliquot", case_id = "1a726069-0b44-42ad-9a20-0ee90b31796b", 
            entity_id = "30e8a34f-c885-4f24-a953-62a63404e05b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(entity_submitter_id = "TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05", 
            entity_type = "aliquot", case_id = "1a726069-0b44-42ad-9a20-0ee90b31796b", 
            entity_id = "30e8a34f-c885-4f24-a953-62a63404e05b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(entity_submitter_id = "TCGA-BQ-7059-01A-11D-1963-05", 
            entity_type = "aliquot", case_id = "1bf54408-b5cb-45dc-ad03-ef2866a0ff59", 
            entity_id = "49aea282-d7d1-4a41-bbf9-35333bd8272d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(entity_submitter_id = "TCGA-AL-3468-01A-01D-1191-05", 
            entity_type = "aliquot", case_id = "2272c592-b9b6-4483-9f7f-6e185699b900", 
            entity_id = "e866cc80-41c7-4f25-8d67-d8e142b62c0c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    file_name = c("0d0f3daf-5dd1-4d41-9a90-605affdb82a6_noid_Grn.idat", 
    "2fb21586-5993-4169-a2e6-fd9ded45225e_noid_Red.idat", "2fb21586-5993-4169-a2e6-fd9ded45225e_noid_Grn.idat", 
    "e079a20c-6cdc-4b74-afdf-3fee58f0b574_noid_Red.idat", "66e13fcd-b609-4e31-a19a-d879d8c6f12f_noid_Grn.idat"
    ), submitter_id = c("d3bb0303-6007-408d-b090-80a4e1123bdf", 
    "24a44261-6b0a-4342-975c-0b78964f8c93", "a83231be-5906-436b-8296-f14dea4618d5", 
    "8e0c4d73-7117-4ef9-aa95-f8fdb5656f30", "23490db6-53b6-499f-adc0-40b84fbd8408"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
TCGA-B3-4103-11A-01D-1191-05
TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05
TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05
TCGA-BQ-7059-01A-11D-1963-05
TCGA-AL-3468-01A-01D-1191-05
```

Answer (score 0):

(0) Modifying "your" loop, but saving the numbers in a vector instead of printing.

```
values_from_entity_submitter_id <- character()

for(rows in idat.meta$associated_entities) {
  values_from_entity_submitter_id <- c(values, rows[[1]])
}
```

(1) By using `sapply`:

```
sapply(idat.meta$associated_entities, \(x) x$entity_submitter_id)
```

(2) By `unnest`ing the dataframes and `extract`ing the relevant column:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

idat.meta |> 
  unnest_wider(associated_entities) |>
  pull(entity_submitter_id)
```

Output:

```
[1] "TCGA-B3-4103-11A-01D-1191-05" "TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05" "TCGA-B3-4103-01A-01D-1191-05" "TCGA-BQ-7059-01A-11D-1963-05"
[5] "TCGA-AL-3468-01A-01D-1191-05"
```

**Edit: Adding your loop (modified).**